# Adding Hyperlink to Pandas DataFrame Makes it a Non Type Object instead of DataFrame

Tags: python, html, pandas

I'm trying to add a clickable hyperlink to my dataframe, which I've done successfully, but then when I try to use JoogleChart to create drop downs and make the data more manageable for users, I get this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'columns'

```
[IN]: def candidate_url(row): return """<a       
href="hirecentral.corp.indeed.com/candidates? application_id=
{}&from=candidate_search" target="_blank">{reqtitle}</a> 
""".format(row['application_id'], 

reqtitle = row.application_id) final['candidate_link'] = 
final.apply(candidate_url, axis=1) 

[IN]: h = final.to_html(escape=True) 

[IN]: chart = JoogleChart(h, chart_type = 'Table', allow_nulls = True) 
chart.show()
```

Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: Instead of an image, please put your code in text.

Comment: Edit your question with that.  Make sure to format it to be readable.

Comment: does that work..